# At least one output file must be specified

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am using this command in ffmpeg

```
   ffmpeg -i test.flv -i /var/www/phpvibe/logo.gif -filter_complex "scale=1200:-1,overlay=0:0" -s 1280x720 -vcodec libx264 -s 640x360 -movflags test.mp4 2>&1
```

But i am getting this

```
 string(42) "At least one output file must be specified"
```

updated:-

php code:-

```
 $output ='{ffmpeg-cmd} -i {input} -i /var/www/phpvibe/logo.gif -filter_complex "scale=1200:-1,overlay=0:0" -s 1280x720 -vcodec libx264 -s {ffmpeg-vsize} -threads 4 -movflags {output}.mp4 2>&1';
```

Complete output:-

```
  array(33) {
  [0]=>
 string(83) "ffmpeg version git-2015-05-11-94c20de Copyright (c)  2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers"
 [1]=>
 string(51) "  built with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)"
 [2]=>
string(243) "  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3"
[3]=>
  string(40) "  libavutil      54. 23.101 / 54. 23.101"
[4]=>
string(40) "  libavcodec     56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100"
[5]=>
string(40) "  libavformat    56. 32.100 / 56. 32.100"
[6]=>
string(40) "  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100"
[7]=>
string(40) "  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101"
[8]=>
string(40) "  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101"
[9]=>
string(40) "  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100"
[10]=>
string(40) "  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100"
[11]=>
string(47) "Trailing options were found on the commandline."
[12]=>
string(31) "Input #0, flv, from 'test.flv':"
[13]=>
 string(11) "  Metadata:"
[14]=>
string(28) "    audiosize       : 150117"
 [15]=>
 string(26) "    canSeekToEnd    : true"
 [16]=>
 string(29) "    datasize        : 1015662"
 [17]=>
 string(26) "    hasAudio        : true"
 [18]=>
 string(27) "    hasCuePoints    : false"
 [19]=>
 string(26) "    hasKeyframes    : true"
 [20]=>
 string(26) "    hasMetadata     : true"
 [21]=>
 string(26) "    hasVideo        : true"
 [22]=>
 string(24) "    lasttimestamp   : 42"
 [23]=>
 string(72) "    metadatacreator : flvtool++ (Facebook, Motion project, dweatherford)"
 [24]=>
 string(25) "    totalframes     : 229"
 [25]=>
 string(28) "    videosize       : 856032"
 [26]=>
 string(59) "  Duration: 00:00:42.27, start: 0.066000, bitrate: 192 kb/s"
 [27]=>
 string(124) "    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 176x144 [SAR 12:11 DAR 4:3], 165 kb/s, 30.30 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc"
 [28]=>
 string(64) "    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 8000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 29 kb/s"
 [29]=>
 string(48) "Input #1, gif, from '/var/www/phpvibe/logo.gif':"
 [30]=>
string(29) "  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A"
 [31]=>
 string(67) "    Stream #1:0: Video: gif, bgra, 90x55, 100 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc"
 [32]=>
 string(42) "At least one output file must be specified"
}
int(1)
```

Comment: You should show your PHP code and the complete output from `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put a `-movflags` without specifying a value before your output file. It thinks `test.mp4` is the flag value hence your problem.